# Restore database keeping views

Tags: sql-server

I have a script that download an SQL Server backup from SAAS product every night.

I can't change the original database and I created 2 views on the database.

Is there a way to keep the views that I created while restoring a new version of the DB?

Comment: A restore returns the database to how it was when the backup was taken. If the views weren't in the database then they won't be when it's restored. You'll have to create them after you restore it again.

Comment: In what's written the script? You could use `SSIS` to call the script and then apply the DDL operation (to create the views) to the DB after the restore is completed.

Comment: Find your views in SSMS, right click them and choose `Script View As` > `Create to` > `New Query Window`. Save that code and then when you restore the database run your view scripts you just saved. As long as the database objects still exist with the same name, your views will be recreated. Problem solved.

Comment: @gbeaven Yes I already thought about this solution, I was wondering if there is a way to restore just the tables data.

Comment: You can put them in a second database that you don't restore each day and have the views use 3-part names to reference the db that you do restore each day.

Comment: No there is no way to do a partial restore. That is sort of like saying you want to use windows restore but only for a couple of folders.